# Can't load an Image file onto my class

Tags: image, javafx

```
  public class Picture extends Application  {




   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    Pane pane = new HBox(100);
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
```

Next I am trying to upload an image form class package

I have copied the image file from my laptop into the

same package as where this class is (Picture)

```
    Image image = new Image("https://
    picturethismaths.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/fig6bigfor
    blog.png?w=419&h=364");
```

Next I am trying to upload an image from online

```
    /*Image image2 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Image image = 
    new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(\"pic.png\"));\n" +
    " title.setImage(image);"));*/


    /* This is the ERROR it gives me ----->> Caused by: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource 
    not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:983)*/




    pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

    ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image);
    imageView2.setFitHeight(100);
    imageView2.setFitWidth(100);
    pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);

    ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(image);
    imageView3.setRotate(90);
    pane.getChildren().add(imageView3);

    Scene scene= new Scene(pane);
    primaryStage.setTitle("ShowImage");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  }
```

I know this question been before, but believe me I have tried all the solutions given in the answers any nothing worked.
Please only ones who want to help write, no Jokers!

Comment: Post the code, uncommented, that actually produces the error, and post the *complete* error message in the question. It's hard to tell what you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If the image you want to load is in the same directory as the class then try

```
Image image2 = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("pic.png"));
```